# Prevent hooks from parent mode in derived mode

Tags: auto-fill-mode, nxml, derived-mode

I have:

```
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'turn-on-auto-fill)
```

but in `lisp/nxml/nxml-mode.el`:

```
(define-derived-mode nxml-mode text-mode "nXML"
```

All XML files is opened with `auto-fill-mode`. That is inconvenient because XML file under source control and shouldn't drastically change on edits.

How can I disable `auto-fill` for nxml? Should I remove:

```
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'turn-on-auto-fill)
```

or add some workaround for `nxml`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Prevent hooks from parent mode in derived mode

Not trivial. I certainly can't think of a nice approach. You may find https://stackoverflow.com/a/19295380 of interest, though.

> How can I disable auto-fill for nxml?

The *trivial* approach is to simply switch it off in `nxml-mode-hook`. The mode will be switched on, and almost immediately switched off again.

```el
(add-hook 'nxml-mode-hook 'turn-off-auto-fill)
```

Alternatively, replace `'turn-on-auto-fill` in your code with a custom function that does what you really want:

```el
(defun my-turn-on-auto-fill-maybe ()
  "Turns on `auto-fill-mode' unless I don't want it."
  (let ((exceptions '(nxml-mode)))
    (unless (apply 'derived-mode-p exceptions)
      (auto-fill-mode 1))))
```

Comment: From your explanation I see that `(add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'turn-on-auto-fill)` is bad defaults. It's better to turn on where I need then add exceptions.

Comment: FWIW, the first option does retain the `flyspell-mode` messages, i.e., the minibuffer talks about `flyspell-mode` even though it's disabled, which confused me a bit.